# Isn't Slug redundant, when Bleed oversteps the page and Bleed < Slug?

Tags: print-design, terminology

1. I read
   [Scott's explanation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46553/why-are-the-bleed-and-slug-lines-outside-my-pages/46554#46554), but Slug still feels redundant to me. Because Bleed < Slug, then whenever you cut the paper at Bleed, you inescapably will have cut off the Slug simultaneously.
2. What does Scott mean by "**actual stock**"?

> Bleeds are used to ensure any trimming which may be slightly inaccurate does not result in the **actual stock** showing at the edge of the piece. Slugs are only used to pass along production notes and are never intended to be part of any actually printed piece a reader would see.

https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/set-print-bleed.html

[image]

http://www.theinformedillustrator.com/2016/07/trim-bleed-live-area-dimensions-for.html

[The Informed Illustrator: Trim, Bleed, & Live Area Dimensions For Printing](http://www.theinformedillustrator.com/2016/07/trim-bleed-live-area-dimensions-for.html)

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference....

Bleed - contains art which has been extended beyond the trim area, so that when trimmed, the art appears to run to the edge of the page.

Slug - contains **unique** items/art, such as a text label for the art so it can be discerned from other artwork, which is *not* part of the final artwork present in the trim or bleed area. Slugs are *unrelated*, visually, to the final piece of art.

**Example:** Imagine, you are getting frames of a film printed as posters. Each frame looks *very* similar with only minute changes. Each frame, as set up for press, would have a trim and bleed area. In order to more easily distinguish frames from one another, in the *slug area* you may print some text to identify *that* frame such as *"film 143 frame number 23"*. This slug printing allows the trimmer to stack the frames in the proper order, or to ensure the same frame number is always gathered in the same stack *without* the need or ability to look at the *actual* artwork and determine differences.

Slugs are used for additional information that is not, and should not, ever be part of the final artwork after trim.

Slugs are most often additional areas at the top or bottom of a piece, outside the bleed. They don't generally encompass the entire document, although they can.

One could state that registration targets and color bars, while more standard, are along the same lines as slug data - i.e. used for production purposes and not part of the final artwork to be delivered.

Comment: Just want to add that, in my area at least, slug is rarely used. The few times I've encountered it, it's only used for information to me as the prepress worker. When I impose the files on printing sheets, I need to have certain distances and include certain marks. I can't take special care to preserve whatever the client has put in the slug. It also clutters the printing sheet.

Comment: @Wolff thats not the point, you could use the slug for some internal processes. Just because you dont does not mean that there could not be some use to do this. It is like i put QR codes on my castings so i can track the batch, it will almost certainly be machined away. But its not like i can use a marker on the metal when its red hot and molten.

Comment: @joojaa, fair enough. One should know what the word means. I'm just saying if you don't have some specific use for it, don't feel obligated to find some excuse for using a slug.